# How can I make jQuery location.search work more efficiently with a regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So, I've got some jQuery code that's hiding the ".toggle-featured" div (Featured section) on any page other than the blog index pages of this site (in development), for example: http://sabq-dev.squarespace.com/experts/

It works fine, but I know there's got to be a better way to achieve the same result with less redundant js.

Here's an example of what I've got currently:

```
(function($){

if(location.search == "?category=Creativity-Intelligence"){
  $('.toggle-featured').hide();
}

})(jQuery);
```

Then I'm repeating this for each category query (10 more which constitute the links in the Filter Categories navigation bar and are the same for every blog section), when I believe that all I really need is the correct regex to have the script find any query prepended with "?=category" and then hide the ".toggle-featured" div. Hopefully that makes sense?

Thus far, all my reading up on regular expressions has gotten me nowhere and I'm sure it's something relatively simple, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Should this code be hiding a specific `.toggle-featured` element, or *all of them* (as it appears to be doing in your code)?

Comment: All of them, yes. Thanks! Looks like either of the answers below will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ( /\?category=/.test(location.search) ) {
```

It checks whether `?category=` is a substring of `location.search`. For this particular test, you needn't resort to a regex,

```
if ( location.search.indexOf("?category=") >= 0) {
```

Would work as well.

The backslash is necessary to escape the special meaning of `?` in regex Syntax (zero or one occurrence).

Comment: Wow that's so simple. Thanks so much! Seems like either answer here's going to work. I'll try both!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is find a set string, you can do this:

```
var s = location.search;
if(s.indexOf('?category=') != -1) {
  $('.toggle-featured').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I used collapsar's answer above and it's working perfectly. Much appreciated!!